# WebView back button logs out user

Tags: android, android-webview

Steps taken:

> **1.** User opens app (*~/home/* which is login page)
>
> **2.** User logs in (now url is *~/home/profile/*)
>
> **3.** User clicks a link (eg. *~/home/profile/photos/*)
>
> **4.** User clicks back (now url is *~/home/profile/* ofc)
>
> **5.** User clicks back again (now url is *~/home/* and **user gets signed out**

How can I make sure the user stays logged in (redirects from ~/home/ to ~/home/profile/ as if you we're signing in. There seem to be no cookies involved.

```
public void onCreate( Bundle b ) {
    super.onCreate( b );
    ...

    this.webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled( true );
    this.webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData( true );
    this.webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled( true );
    this.webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled( true );
    this.webView.loadUrl( URL );
}
```

Comment: have u know webviewclient in android

Comment: you want user to stay logged in when you start your activity again or you want user not to log out when he presses back button from ~/home/profile ?

Comment: Both. But there was a problem with the page rather than the app. I fixed this by using `webView.clearHistory();` when the user signs in.

Comment: If you want "User to stay logged in when you start activity again" then store the login credentials in Shared Preferences of your application. Next time you come to that activity you can by pass the login screen and directly redirect to other screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`webView.clearHistory();`
when the user signed in (reached **2**) and if the user tried to go back further I made a dialog show up that asks if the user wants to exit app.